# ES6 Import for underscore.deepclone extension in angular

Tags: angular, import, underscore.js, es6-modules

There is a deep-clone extension for underscore.

[underscore.deepclone](https://github.com/mateusmaso/underscore.deepclone)

The readme says for node to use

```
var _ = require('underscore');
_.mixin(require('underscore.deepclone'));
```

I want to use this in my frontend angular projects and I usually import underscore with this

```
import * as _ from 'underscore';
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
// Import all underscore methods into variable "_"
import * as _ from 'underscore';

// Import function from package "underscore.deepclone" into variable "deepclone"
import deepclone from 'underscore.deepclone';

//Create mixin with _.mixin method
_.mixin(deepclone);

//Now you can do deep clone for your object:
//var someClone = _.deepclone(someObject)
```